# How to use ng-model / bind in different views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a view for my `app-header` and view for body content `ng-view`. Basically I have a ng-model input in the profile body and when that is loaded up, I want to bind it to something in the header.

If the ng-model and the binding are in the same view I have no problem, but not sure how to get the binding to go across scopes:

```
<!-- Main Nav -->
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="content_container">
    <!-- angular templating content will be injected here -->
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Input in profile component

```
<input ng-model="profile_name" type="text" id="profile_first_name" name="profile_first_name"/>
```

Header

```
<div class="user_badge">{{profile_name}}</div>
```

Header Directive

```
// Directive for Header
app.directive('appHeader', function () {
    // Type of Directive, E for element, A for Attribute
    // url of a template
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'shared/navigation/header.html'
    };
});
```

ProfileController

```
// Controller for Profile
app.controller('ProfileController', function() {
});

// Controller for Complete Registration
app.controller('CompleteRegistrationController', function() {
});

// configure our routes
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route : Edit Profile
    .when('/profile', {
        title : 'Edit Profile',
        templateUrl : 'components/profile/edit-profile.html',
        controller  : 'ProfileController'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to link to where?

Comment: I think he just wants to update the profile name in the title while typing the profile name in the edit profile partial below that title. I think I would solve something like that with a factory. You can inject it whereever you need access to the user repository and it is easily testable. Would that be an option?

Comment: Yeah that would be great, haven't used factories yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're having a problem with parent/child scoping. There is a quote about `ng-model` you will see a lot: "If you don't have a dot, you're doing it wrong". This is because of the way prototypal inheritance works.

The solution is to define the model as an object in the parent scope.

```
<input ng-model="profile.name" type="text" />
```

and

```
<div class="user_badge">{{profile.name}}</div>
```

And in the parent scope:

```
$scope.profile = {};
```

This way, when the model is updated the reference to the parent scope is not overwritten, but the model data is updated.

Take a look at the angular guide for scopes if you want to learn more about how it really works: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

---

**Edit**

Here's a snippet showing it working with parent/child scope. It should work exactly the same for `ng-view` which just adds the controller dynamically.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('appHeader', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="user_badge">{{profile.name}}</div>'
    };
  })
  .controller('ChildCtrl', function() {
  })
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.profile = {
      name: 'Test'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <app-header></app-header>

    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
      <input ng-model="profile.name" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to get this to work now. My parent scope for everything is PortalController... I added `$scope.profile = { name : 'Eric' };` but still not getting anything just yet